# What "Socket Error # 2" means in Indy components?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy10

I have created an application that calls a web service using POST method in C++/Delphi. It works fine in the localhost under http, but when I try the https protocol in the production server, I get  "Socket Error # 2". I have no idea what it means. The web server is providing https services to other applications (not Rad Studio) without problems. The code I use is extracted from a web site:

```cpp
std::auto_ptr<TIdHTTP> httpPtr( new TIdHTTP(NULL) );
TIdHTTP *Http = httpPtr.get();
try
{
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL *SSL = new TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL( Http );
  // configure SSL settings as needed...
  Http->IOHandler = SSL;

  Http->HandleRedirects = true;
  Http->AllowCookies = false;
  Http->ConnectTimeout = 10000;
  Http->ReadTimeout = 10000;

  Http->Request->BasicAuthentication = true;
  Http->Request->Password = username;
  Http->Request->Username = password;

  Memo1->Text = Http->Post( "http://logs.domain.dk", json);
}
catch( const Exception &e )
{
  Memo1->Lines->Add(e.ClassName());
  Memo1->Lines->Add(e.Message);
  return;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have added the following code to see the messages from Fiddler.

```cpp
IdHTTP1->ProxyParams->ProxyServer = "127.0.0.1"; 
IdHTTP1->ProxyParams->ProxyPort = 8888;
```

Now it works fine (with the Proxy for Fiddler), but of course, it is not the solution because the user will not have Fiddler. 
I do not know if it is important, but the https server does not use the normal https port. It uses 4001, but I pass this value in the url:

```cpp
IdHTTP1->Post("https://myweb.com:4001/api/certificate", json);
```

What is happening? I am confused.

Comment: Could you please post the exact Socket Error number. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: After calling iHTTP1->Post(), an exception is raised. The only information I can get is CLASSNAME: EIdSocketError, MESSAGE:Socket Error # 2. How can get the Socket Error number?

Comment: Catch `EIdSocketError` instead of `Exception` and print out the exception's [`LastError`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=EIdSocketError_LastError.html). That is the socket error code.

Comment: Done. The LastError value is 2. It is the same number of general exception "Socket Error # 2". Regrettably Windows Sockets Error Codes document does not  mention the #2 code.

Comment: 2 is not a valid socket error code on Windows.  You should not be seeing 2 reported.  This makes me think that you are using an older version of Indy that had problems with socket error reporting when SSL is enabled. That was fixed a long time ago. What versions of C++Builder and Indy are you actually using?

Comment: What version of Delphi? Please do not use the `rad-studio` tag, it's deprecated and is not meant to be used. Please use the tag corresponding to the specific version of Delphi. It makes a major difference in how we're able to identify your problem. I have a feeling error code `2` is something custom in code that you can only see. As others are telling you, there is no such socket error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem happens with Indy + SSL + Windows 8.1

The solution is simply to add:

```
IdHTTP1->ReadTimeout = 30000;
```

Problem solved!

Comment: You have not answered the questions that were asked. The questions asked regard what error #2 means and "what is happening." Your answer doesn't address either of those things.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what #2 means. It seems a bug of my XE version. In any case, the purpose of the question was to be able to run the application without errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below line to the section :
`ssl->SSLOptions->Method = TIdSSLVersion::sslvSSLv23;`